# Automatic startup of Ubuntu installed alongside windows?

Tags: dual-boot, startup

I bought an emachines desktop about two years ago and I installed Ubuntu 11.04 alongside recently.  On startup of the machine I get an option to go ahead and run Windows or I can scroll down to Ubuntu.

Now, there is nothing wrong with this and both operating systems work flawlessly but I find it an annoyance to have to stay at my computer to make it run Ubuntu, i.e. I can't turn it on and leave and have it automatically run Ubuntu.  How can I change this so that Ubuntu is the "default" operating system to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [startupmanager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/startupmanager) [image: Install startupmanager] for that. It's available from the repositories.